# Lookup an array of IDs, and map them to an array of items in a separate schema

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, promise

I have an `outfits` database, in which each outfit is an array of unique ids. I also have a separate database of items, each of which has a unique id.

I'm trying to take a set of arrays from `outfits` and get details of the corresponding items.

I've written a function to lookup items by Id, and send them to the front end, but I can't seem to maintain the array structure in the response.

```
exports.outfitRendered = (req, res) => {
var outfits = [["5c25109c07c4dd627126a1a6", "5c25109c07c4dd627126a1a6"], ["5c25109c07c4dd543126a1a6"]];

// CREATE SOME EMPTY ARRAYS
var newArray = []
var outerArray = []

// LOOK UP THE ITEMS IN THE OUTFIT FROM USER DB
function lookup(outfitId) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        for (y of outfitId) {
            //console.log(y);
            User.aggregate([
                { $match: { '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id) } },
                { $unwind: '$wardrobe.items' },
                { $match: { 'wardrobe.items._id': y } },
                { $project: { 'wardrobe.items': 1, '_id': 0 } }
            ]).then(function (res) {
                newArray.push(res)
            }).then(function (resp) {
                resolve(this.newArray);
            });
        }
    });
}


// PUSH ITEMS INTO NEW ARRAY
function build(array) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        for (x of array) {
            console.log(x);
            lookup(x)
                .then(function () {
                    outerArray.push(newArray);
                    console.log('incoming')
                    resolve(this.outerArray);
                })
        }
    });
}


// SEND TO FRONTEND
var ready = build(outfits)
    .then(function () {
        res.json(outerArray);
    });
}
```

This code sends the first value in `var outfits` to the front end, and it looks fine. But I can't figure out how to get the same array structure in the result.

It should look like this

Original: `outfits`:

`[["5c25109c07c4dd627126a1a6", "5c25109c07c4dd627126a1a6"], ["5c25109c07c4dd543126a1a6"]]`

Result: `outerArray`:

`[["Red shirt", "Black pants"], ["Blue jeans"]]`

Comment: What's in newArray and in outerArray right now? Seems like you never clear newArray and keep appending to it, so outerArray will end up with duplicates.

Comment: `res.json(outerArray)` includes the first item from the `outfits` array. It looks fine, but it's just the first value.

If I `console.log(newArray)` where it appears in the loop, I get 3 logs which end up like this:
`[ [ { wardrobe: [Object] } ], [ { wardrobe: [Object] } ], [ { wardrobe: [Object] } ] ]`

Each time it adds a new item, which is _almost_ what I want. But if you look at the above, all items are in the same array. It should be [ [ [item 1], [item 2] ], [item 3] ] ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const items = { "5c25109c07c4dd587126a1a6": "Red shirt", "5c25109c07c4dd627126a1a6": "Black pants", "5c25109c07c4dd543126a1a6": "Blue jeans" };
const outfits = [
  ["5c25109c07c4dd587126a1a6", "5c25109c07c4dd627126a1a6"],
  ["5c25109c07c4dd543126a1a6"]
];

function getItem(itemId) {
  return items[itemId];
  /*return User.aggregate([
    { $match: { '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id) } },
    { $unwind: '$wardrobe.items' },
    { $match: { 'wardrobe.items._id': itemId } },
    { $project: { 'wardrobe.items': 1, '_id': 0 } }
  ]);*/
}

function lookupItems(outfits) {
  return Promise.all(outfits.map(itemIds => {
    return Promise.all(itemIds.map(getItem))
  }));
}

lookupItems(outfits).then(items => {
  console.log(items);
});
```